# How to use a REST proximity search to find speed limits and roadway information?

Tags: here-api

I am new to using here.com and am struggling with what I believe is a basic query. I have a series of gps coordinates from roadways in the Southern US and I would like to pair the coordinate data with associated speed limits and road information (e.g., functional class).

I am trying to use the proximity search function but I keep getting an error that I am not able to clearly trace.

The base of my query is using

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/search/proximity.json
```

I then append my app_id and code, and set proximity to a GPS coordinate. For example:

```
proximity=29.70127,-95.40907
```

Then per the api instructions at: [Here.com proximity search](https://developer.here.com/documentation/platform-data/topics/resource-search-proximity.html)

I enter a layer ID and key attributes. For example to find the speed limit:

```
layer_ids=SPEED_LIMITS_FC1&key_attributes=FROM_REF_SPEED_LIMIT
```

When I submit the query I get the following error:

```
{
  "faultCode": "704a79f6-20f3-4fa6-874c-5741dcaf1feb",
  "responseCode": "400",
  "message": "Provided layer does not contain geometries."
}
```

It seems based on the message that I may be using the incorrect layer, however, I do know that the attributes I am asking for are present with the layer. Also, I have tried other FC (1-5) variants of the layer without success. It is not clear to me what "geometries" is referring to in the error message.

I have also checked with other more basic queries to ensure that my app_id and app_code are correctly entered and that there are no network connectivity issues.

Answer (score 0):

The error messages is saying.
SPEED_LIMITS_FC1 is not a thematic Layer containing geometries.
You can confirm the detail Layers in below link. layer type must be "geom" for /search/proximity.
 https://pde.api.here.com/1/doc/layers.json?app_id={{app_id}}&app_code={{app_code}}&region=WEU

Here is a sample.

```
https://pde.api.here.com/1/search/proximity.json?app_code={{app_code}}&app_id={{app_id}}&layer_ids=LINK_FC1&proximity=29.680334933229688,-95.39327178890237,100&key_attributes=LINK_ID
```

I hope this help.

Comment: It helps in showing how to get `LINK_FC1` attributes, but not how to get `SPEED_LIMITS_FC1` attributes with the retrieved `LINK_ID`.